# Html5: Form Validation 'required' not working

Tags: html, forms

Okay, so I'm working on a form for a website, and I came across a problem. So when I try to validate the form in html5 it does not work right. I don't know if there's something I need to do. I want to make it so when I submit the button then it would show the errors. But it doesn't it goes to the next page.

I don't know what do, can someone help me.

Here is the form.

```
<form>
   <strong>
      <p style="color:#63bbff">First Name:
   </strong>
   <input type="text" name="name" required ><br /></p>
   <strong>
      <p style="color:#63bbff">Minecraft Username(IGN):  
   </strong>
   <input type="text" name="ign" required ><br /></p>
   <strong>
      <p style="color:#63bbff">Age: 
   </strong>
   <input type="text" name="age" required ><br /></p>
   <em>
      <p style="color:#63bbff">When you understand the stated above, and ready to continue, click the button 'Continue'
      <p>
   </em>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue" onclick="window.location='Index-3.html'" class="btn">
</form>
<button class="button" onclick="window.location='Index.html'">Previous</button>
```

Comment: You aren't submitting the form but using a nasty piece of JavaScript to redirect to a separate page... And you run that code unconditionally, even if the form is invalid.

Comment: Be careful, you have `<strong><p></strong>` -> you should put you `<strong>` inside your `<p>`. But that is not the problem here. As said before, the `onclick` on the submit button doesn't actually submit the form. You can use `submit()` javascript function or not use javascript at all for form submission

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to write OnSubmit for form.

```
<form onsubmit="Index-3.html" >
```

and remove Window.Location from submit button. Check your demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6sYB/)

Answer (score 0):

just use `<form onsubmit="further()">` and the submit field like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue" class="btn">
```

then the js:

```
function further(){
  window.location='Index-3.html';
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swL9t/

**OR**:

just simply use `<form action="Index-3.html">` and your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue" class="btn">
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swL9t/2/

Answer (score 0):

please replace onclick="window.location='Index-3.html'" with **onsubmit**="window.location='Index-3.html'"